# ActiveAdmin Tabs lazy loading content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

i am using ActiveAdmin to show admin graphs to the users. I have a show page with tabs, For each tab i show some graphs, but actually since the show method is called when the user requests the page, all the queries to build all the graphs are called, even if the user is seeing only the first tab. The queries are heavy, so the loading time of that page is large.
Is it possible to launch the queries and execute the related code when the user click on the single tab?

Comment: is there a way to 'configure' this behavior without implementing everything from scratch, intercepting the click even, building the async call to the server etc?

Comment: There is no such 'configure' way, write code, it's fun.

Comment: @Зелёный How to do it?

Comment: @red-devil how to do what?

Comment: How to make the tabs lazy load with active admin?